# Создать простейший текстовый процессор, содержащий переключатели цвета шрифта, флажки для определения стиля

Tags: c#, winforms

Нужно сделать так что бы после выделение 2х checkBox ,снимаем выделение с одного, то второе должно остаться. Переключатели цвета я сделала, и если выделить checkBox то работает, но при снятие выделения ничего не меняется.(Использовать нужно WindowsForm)

```
    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkBox1.Checked)
                textBox1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font(textBox1.Font, textBox1.Font.Style ^ System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
        }

        private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkBox2.Checked)
                textBox1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font(textBox1.Font, textBox1.Font.Style ^ System.Drawing.FontStyle.Italic);
        }

        private void checkBox3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkBox3.Checked)
                textBox1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font(textBox1.Font, textBox1.Font.Style ^ System.Drawing.FontStyle.Underline);
```

Comment: например, что можете предложить?

Comment: Давайте говорящие имена всем программным сущностям. Чтобы глядя в код, можно было сразу понять, для чего они. Например, назовите чекбоксы `boldCheckBox`, `italicCheckBox`, `underlineCheckBox`. И т. п.